# How can I get the global search in VSCode to work?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I encounter a question while I am using Visual Studio Code on Mac, I used to kill a process related to the search function on VS Code(Sorry I forgot the process name) because of the high CPU usage.

After that, I found that the global search does not work in VS Code any more, sometimes I really need this function to search file or open file in a quick way; I have searched many times but can not get the solution. So I go to here and asking for help.

When I use command + p to search file by name, the rate of process is always on loading, it can only list those files which I have opened, other files even they are matched by name will not be shown in list.

So I want to make search functions well as usual, how could I do?

Comment: I think I've had problems like this before when I overwrote a search exclude list and left out node_modules or vendor which quickly fill with massive amounts of files. I would check your user and workspace preferences to make sure.

Comment: Yes, It really works, After I removed the `search.exclude` config in my preferences and restart the VSCode, The problem has been solved, Thank u very much :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same issue about 1.5 months ago. Reinstalling fixed the issue for me, but as indicated [this reported bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25923) it can have something to do with your `search.exclude` glob pattern as well. If reinstalling does not fix the issue for you, that linked issue might be the problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Yes, finally I solved this problem by removing the `search.exclude` configuration, Thank u for your help~

Answer (score 15):

If search is only searching on opened files, ensure this sneaky setting 'Search only in Open Editors' is not accidentally enabled.

[image]